# Fluent Nhibernate and HasOne() problems

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

How do you do a 1 to 1 relationship with fluent nhibernate? I am using ms sql server 2008 and every time I looked the db tables through the database diagram viewer the table that should have one to one relationships don't seem to have them.

```
Users
UserId <pk> Guid


Settings
UserId <pk> Guid


public Settings
{
  public virtual Guid UserId {get; private set;}
 public virtual Setting User { get; set; }

}

public User
{
  public virtual Guid UserId {get; private set;}
 public virtual Setting Setting { get; set; }
}


public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
 {
      Id(x => x.UserId);
     HasOne(x => x.Setting);
}

public class SettingMap : ClassMap<Setting>
 {
      Id(x => x.UserId);
     HasOne(x => x.User);
}
```

So I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: What hasn't worked about it? Did it give an error? Did you create tables from it to see the SQL generated? Do you have conventions for your Id mapping, etc...

Comment: @Phil I expect to see a line drawn between the two tables showing a relationship of one to one in the ms sql 2008 server diagram generator. When I generate my table I do not see this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a property of type Setting on your Setting class? It's called User so I would expect it (also because of your description of the problem) that it be a User class instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, couldnt see any relationships being generated. I finally found that this worked:

```
 public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
   public ParentMap()
  {
      Id(x => x.Id);
     HasOne(s => s.Child).Cascade.All();
  }
}

public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Model.Child>
{
   public ChildMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    HasOne(s => s.Parent).Constrained().ForeignKey();           
   }
}
```